# Restricting API access to only server-side app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.7.2

I have an API that would be accessed by another API which is then consumed by a front-end app. So [Web Page] -> [Middleware API] -> [My API]. Is there any way I can make my API private so that it can only be consumed by the middleware API? None of the endpoints will be used by the front end so everything should be server side.

Comment: If "My API" is a web application running on a different back-end server, can that server simply not be exposed to the public internet?

Comment: No because the server is exposed to the public internet as it hosts some websites on IIS

Comment: If the MyAPI-server only has a public-facing interface, you should probably do it as a firewall rule to only allow hitting MyAPI from internal addresses. Or if you want to do it in code, you should probably set up authentication between MiddlewareAPI & MyAPI.